# Square matrix $A$ of order m, such that $||A||_{\max} \lt 1/m$ . Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} A^n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, limits, normed-spaces

$A$ is a square matrix of order m, such that $||A||_{\max} \lt 1/m$ . Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} A^n=0$ 
That is all the information given by the author of the exercise and I don't really know where to start by, since I still find hard this topic, that's why I'd appreciate any hints received.

Comment: What is the definition of $\|A\|_{\textrm{max}}$?

Comment: The definition used by the author for a matrix $A=(a_{ij}); 1 \le i \le p, 1 \le j \le m$, with p rows and m columns \
$||A||_{max} = max |a_{i, j}|; 1 \le i \le p, 1 \le j \le m$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edited: the original answer assumed a different norm(s)]

It can be easily shown that $\|A B\|_{\textrm{max}} \leq m \|A\|_{\textrm{max}} \|B\|_{\textrm{max}}$. Setting $\|A\|_{\textrm{max}} = \alpha < \frac 1m$,
$$
\|A^n - 0\|_{\textrm{max}} = \|A^n\|_{\textrm{max}} \leq \|A\|^n_{\textrm{max}} < (\underbrace{m \alpha}_{<1})^n \to 0.
$$

Since we have established that $\lim \|A^n -0\| = 0$, we conclude that $\lim A^n = 0$.